# Data of two div tag overlapping after zoom in, How i stop it

Tags: html, css

Web page before zoom in
[image: Web page before zoom in]

Web page after zoom in
[image: Web page after zoom in]

When i zoom in my web page that time two side bar menu div overlapping, How i stop that overlapping .Please help.

Please see left bottom footer div and left side menu bar .This two overlapping after zoom in

Comment: Please create a a [mcve] using a stack snippet otherwise your question is off topic and we are unable to help

Comment: Stop zooming in/out. and use **CSS** `@media queries` to control the view in diferents viewports

Answer (score 0):

Zooming in/out changes the resolution so first if your website is not responsive, you should stop zooming in/out.

If above is not the case and you want to fix the issue and as the question is not tagged with any responsive UI framework like bootstrap, assuming you are using only html+css, you can go for [media query css](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

Using media query CSS you can handle CSS of any specific section for different screen resolution, below is an example:

Let's say if the browser window is 600px or smaller, you want to change  the background color to light blue, then you can use below media query CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir, but this solution not working please suggest another solution,

Comment: This is just an example, you will have to write your own CSS to fix the overlapping for different resolutions. Are you using any frontend UI framework like bootstrap or any other?